The proper definition of module actions about the inductive limit of the inductive system
I have a question about how to define a module action on an inductive limit of the inductive system.
If I have  an inductive system of vector spaces $$\left\{ \left( V_k \right) _{k\ge 1},\left( \varphi _{l,k} \right) _{1\le l,k} \right\} $$
where $\varphi _{l,k}:V_l\to V_k$ is a homomorphism of vector space, satisfying
$(1)$: $\varphi _{l,l}=id$
$(2)$: $\varphi _{ik}=\varphi _{jk}\circ \varphi _{ij}$ for all $i\le j\le k$.
Then we can define inductive limit $V=\underrightarrow{\lim }V_k$ of $\left\{ \left( V_k \right) _{k\ge 1},\left( \varphi _{l,k} \right) _{1\le l,k} \right\}$ just as on Direct limit.
Here is my question:
If I also have a ring $R$ with an identity and I want to define a $R$-module structure of $V$, What conditions should be satisfied for this module action?
